# Is there a 100% sure way to stop a thread after all other threads finish their jobs in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one consumer thread and several producer threads sharing a job list. The producer threads end when their "limit of producing" is reached. However, i could not get hold of ending consumer thread successfully without using "Interrupt".

I am trying to stop the consumer thread. In consumer thread, i have used a AtomicBoolean variable (JDK 1.6) for stopping the loop inside run method. But, i could not find a way in the main class to get to know that all producer threads have ended. Tried using join on producer threads in main class.

Note that as all threads are running at once. The current code in my main class abruptly ends the consumer thread without completing all the jobs. I am looking for an answer without using

> ExecutorService/Future/Callable.

Following the code snippet from my main method:

```
//Job container
JobContainer<CalcJob> jobContainer = new JobContainer<CalcJob>(100);

//One Consumer
Consumer consumer = new Consumer(jobContainer);
Thread T0 = new Thread(consumer);
T0.start();

//Multiple Producers
JobProducer jobProducer = new JobProducer(jobContainer, 0, 10); 
Thread T1 = new Thread(jobProducer);
T1.start();


JobProducer jobProducer1 = new JobProducer(jobContainer, 1, 10);
Thread T2 = new Thread(jobProducer1);
T2.start();

//Join statements
T0.join();
T1.join();
T2.join();

//Stop consumer
consumer.stop(new AtomicBoolean(true));
```

Comment: What about having a `boolean` field in the `JobProducer` that lets you know if the work has finished? This field starts as `false` and after finishing its job changes to `true` to *notify* to client.

Comment: you want me to check all JobProducer's boolean field in main method?

Comment: Well, what else you may do? This is a very naive approach and you should at least have a `Thread[]` instead of having multiple manual `Thread x1, x2, ... xn` in your code. Or even better, use the non-desired `ExecutorService` that already handles this kind of problems.

Comment: Why "without using interrupt"?  It's going to be hard to get the consumer's attention any other way if it's waiting on a blocking queue.

Comment: On the other hand, what if you _don't_ stop it?  What if you make the consumer a daemon thread.  Then the JVM will kill it when the last non-daemon thread dies.

Comment: By not using interrupt meant to handle it through a way without  generating exception. Without ExecutorService meant, i want my own method to be implemented. I agree with Luiggi, that i should use Thread[]/list. Still, the problem persists.

Comment: I want to kill the consumer thread in my code.

Comment: In some other posts, i read that using a flag for stopping thread is not really recommended...wait-notify is recommended. Any solutions?

Comment: I just went through Joshua Bloch's Effective Java book, in it he suggests the flag method to be used to stop a thread. However, he admits that it did not work on his machine! :) So my 50% success rate comment holds true...

Comment: Why "without generating exception?"

Comment: Here's another suggestion, if you _really_ don't want to use interrupt().  Set the "done" flag, and then put some kind of a "no-op" task in the queue.  Then your consumer thread will wake up because something is available to take from the queue, and it can notice that the flag is set, and return from its run() method.

Comment: Threads should be cooperating and coded to do what you want them to do. If you feel you need to reach into a thread from another thread and make it do something, that should tell you that you coded that thread wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CountDownLatch` with enough permits for all producers. When a producer finisher producing, it counts down. Have one (extra) thread wait on the latch, and then kill the consumer/perform any cleanup.

Comment: It's Bad Form to have one thread kill another.  Threads should cooperate.  When it's time for a long-running thread to stop, some other thread should set a flag and (if necessary) interrupt it.  Then the interrupted thread should clean up whatever it needs to clean up, and return from its top-level run() method.

Answer (score 0):

I did a work around. In the main method, i modified the last part of the above code as follows,

```
        //Wait until all jobs are processed
        while(false == jobContainer.isEmpty()){
        synchronized(jobContainer){
        jobContainer.wait(100);
        }
    }
    //once job list is empty, stop the consumer
    calculator.stop(new AtomicBoolean(true));
```

Note: I can move that code inside JobContainer as well...

Do you guys agree?

Comment: You have to move the entire `while` loop into the `synchronized` block:    `synchronized(jobContainer){while(!jobContainer.isEmpty()) jobContainer.wait(100); }`. And all other access to the `jobContainer`, i.e. the code removing items from it, must happen within a `synchronized(jobContainer)` block as well.